# I can't connect to the internet wirelessly through xUbuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, xubuntu

Complete beginner here. Have installed ubuntu through vmware player on my laptop. Can connect to the internet fine on windows but not through ubuntu. I have been trying to follow this [guide](http://docs.xubuntu.org/1304/internet-networks.html#network-troubleshoothing-wifi-on). The network icon allows me to check "enable networking" but there is no "enable wireless" coming up at all. I followed the "check if the device is recognized" and got this output:

```
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id: 1
bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
logical name: eth0
version: 10
serial: 00:0c:29:ee:f3:26
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master rom ethernet physical logical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=pcnet32 driverversion=1.35 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=255 mingnt=6 multicast=yes
resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=128) memory:e7b00000-e7b0ffff
```

It doesn't say enabled, disabled, claimed or unclaimed anywhere.

I also attempted the "checking for connection to the router" section and got:

```
lo no wireless extensions.


eth0 no wireless extensions.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu living in you virtual machine doesn't connect directly to networks with the wifi card Windows uses.

The virtual machine "installs" another virtual network card for your virtual Ubuntu. In your virtual Ubuntu you should try to connect with a wired connection (eth0) that should be installed by default.

There are many modes for the handling of the virtual network connection for fine-grained controls (eg: allow connection with hosts on the lan but not to the net, only allow access to the net, etc.) but the default should work.

This tutorial http://rednectar.net/2011/07/20/vmware-interfaces-tutorial/ might help you.